# EFCore Filter on Property With Contains And List of Values

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to filter entities based on a list of search values within specific fields on the entity.

For example:

```
var searchValues = new List<string> { "abc", "xyz" };
var posts = Context.Posts
    .Where(p => searchValues.Any(v => p.Title.Contains(v)))
    .ToList();
```

This generates an exception "The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

What is the correct way to apply contains filters with multiple search values?

Comment: `from p in Context.Posts from v in searchValues where p.Title.Contains(v) select p`

Comment: Is there an equivalent using the extension methods syntax?

Comment: Of course. The query expression syntax is always translated into the method syntax by the compiler. You should be comfortable with both.

Comment: We don't use the query syntax at all - would you be able to help with the working method syntax? Thanks.

Comment: You should use the query syntax when it is easier to read. `Context.Posts.SelectMany(p => searchValues.Where(v => p.Title.Contains(v)).Select(v => p))` is far less readable. You should learn to understand both.

Comment: I tried your suggested code and it failed with an exception: The LINQ expression 'p => __searchValues_0
    .Where(v => p.Title.Contains(v))
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select(v => p)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. Note that it has automatically injected the AsQueryable() call - this is not in my code.

Comment: Also, extension methods are our preferred option due to nearly always requiring conditional query construction such as where or sort clauses.

Answer (score -1):

If you convert Posts to list before the where it should work.

```
var posts = Context.Posts.ToList()
.Where(p => searchValues.Any(v => p.Title.Contains(v)));
```

That way the filter doesn't have to be translated into SQL (or whatever db you're using).

The catch is that all of the Posts data will be loaded into memory to make the list. This may or may not be acceptable depending on the quantity of Posts and database calls.

Comment: This will work but you should at least warn about the implications.

Comment: Sure - I am aware of the ability to process that filter in-memory but that isn't a desirable option due to volume of data and performance considerations. We only use the extension method syntax so would appreciate it if someone could help with that.

Comment: Wouldn't it cause the whole set of posts to be retrieved from the DB? The whole filtration by where only makes sense if it takes place in the DB server. Otherwise, we simply end up in two operations - one fetching the whole shabang. Then, iterating in-mem filtering on the app server. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. I mentioned that in the last paragraph. But if you don't have a crazy amount of 'Posts' it could be fine. What do you suggest.? Is there a way to rewrite the query in LINQ so that it doesn't cause an error?